# Conserving pixel counts with HEALPy

Tags: python, maps, astronomy, healpy

I have a list of galaxies to plot onto a healpix map (which I'm using healpy to do) each galaxy has a set flux and I need to have them plotted in such a way that the flux for each galaxy is conserved on the map.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import healpy as hp
pi = np.pi

nside = 8
xsize = 100

ra = np.array([pi/4,pi/3])
dec = np.array([pi/4,pi/3])
flux = np.array([10,20])

hpm = np.zeros(hp.nside2npix(nside)) #Blank healpix map
pixindex = hp.ang2pix(nside, dec, ra)

np.add.at(hpm,pixindex,flux) #Add flux onto correct pixels

img=hp.mollview(hpm,coord=['E'],xsize=xsize,return_projected_map=True)
print(np.sum(img[img>0]))
```

The result I get is 140 and not 30 which is the true sum of the fluxes.

I get what is going on and that the same flux is being spread over multiple pixels (6 for the first galaxy and 4 pixels for the second) and I'm aware I could just do:

```
newimg = img * (np.sum(flux)/np.sum(img[img>0]))
```

and this would conserve the total photon count but it wouldn't necessarily conserve the photon count of each galaxy which is what I need. i.e this method ends up with the first galaxy contributing a flux of 12.86 and the second galaxy a flux of 17.14.

Is there a way of working out before how many pixels each coordinate will take up then altering the amount of flux dumped based on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The `xsize` parameter for the function `hp.mollview` should be used for plotting purpose only. If you would like to manipulate the resolution of the map, use `hp.pixelfunc.ud_grade`

For example, if you want to go from `nside=8` to `nside=32`,

After the line

```
np.add.at(hpm, pixindex, flux) #Add flux onto correct pixels
```

use the `ud_grade` function with `power=-2`, so the total flux can be conserved:

```
hpm_nside_32 = hp.pixelfunc.ud_grade(hpm, power=-2, nside_out=32)
```

the sum

```
np.sum(hpm_nside_32)
```

will be conserved at `30`.

I can't offer a solution if you need the mollview to have the flux conserved. The closest I can get is by scaling the img value down based on the ratio of the number of pixels in the mollview image and the number of pixels in the hpm. The first term `xsize * xsize / 2.` is the number of pixels in the mollview, the second term `2. * np.pi / 8.` is the ratio of the area of an ellipse with semi-minor axis half the length of the semi-major axis `pi * r * 2r` to the area of a rectangle `4r * 2r`.

```
len(hpm) / ((xsize * xsize / 2.) * (2. * np.pi / 8.)) * np.sum(img[img > 0])
```

When `xsize = 100`, the sum will become `27.380`; when `xsize = 1000`, the approximation is much better, at `29.981`; when `xsize = 10000`, total flux becomes `29.988`.

An alternative way to give you a good approximation is to compute the ratio of the number of non `-inf` pixels in `img` to the number of pixel in your map (which is `768` for `nside=8`):

```
float(len(hpm)) / float(np.sum(img>=0)) * np.sum(img[img>0])
```

At `xsize = 100, 1000, 10000`, the flux will be at `28.295, 30.075, 29.998` respectively.